# matrix chain mutiplication dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, matrix, pseudocode

```
  // Matrix Ai has dimension p[i-1] x p[i] for i = 1..n
    Matrix-Chain-Order(int p[])
{
// length[p] = n + 1
n = p.length - 1;
// m[i,j] = Minimum number of scalar multiplications (i.e., cost)
// needed to compute the matrix A[i]A[i+1]...A[j] = A[i..j]
// cost is zero when multiplying one matrix
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
   m[i,i] = 0;

for (L=2; L<=n; L++) { // L is chain length
    for (i=1; i<=n-L+1; i++) {
        j = i+L-1;
        m[i,j] = MAXINT;
        for (k=i; k<=j-1; k++) {
            // q = cost/scalar multiplications
            q = m[i,k] + m[k+1,j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
            if (q < m[i,j]) {
                m[i,j] = q;
                // s[i,j] = Second auxiliary table that stores k
                // k      = Index that achieved optimal cost
                s[i,j] = k;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is the pseudocode for matrix chanin multiplication
i cant understand this part

```
  for (L=2; L<=n; L++) { // L is chain length
    for (i=1; i<=n-L+1; i++) {
        j = i+L-1;
        m[i,j] = MAXINT;
```

why are taking i to be less than or equal to (n-L+1)
and j=i+L-1

am a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's pseudocode, and these arrays are 1-based. If you are using a C-like language, that will probably be the first issue, since arrays in C start at index `0` and end at `len-1`, if `len` is the length of array. Next, the variable `n` is chosen to be smaller than the total number of matrices by `1`. If you replace `n` with `p.length - 1`, then it may also become a bit clearer what's going on.

1. You want to run the outer loop (i.e. the chain length `L`) for all possible chain lengths. You start with the smallest chain length (only two matrices) and end with all matrices (i.e. `L` goes from `2` to `n`). Prior to that, the cost array was initialized for the trivial case of only one matrix (i.e. no multiplication).
2. This means that `i` can go from `1` until the last item minus the chain length (`n-L+1`, note that `n` is `p.length - 1` so this is effectively `p.length - L`). For example, if you are currently checking chains of length `4`, your `i` loop would effectively run like this:

   ```
   L = 4;
   for (i = 1; i <= p.length - 4; i++)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

   In C, you would write `for (i = 0; i < p.length - 4; i++)`. Note that `<=` is replaced with `<`.
3. Next, you are trying to get the cost of multiplying chain starting at `i`, of length `L`. This means that the last element in the chain is `j = i + L -1`. Again, if the current chain length is `L`, then you have:

   ```
   L = 4;
   for (i = 1; i <= p.length - 4; i++)
   {
       j = i + 3;
       ...
   }
   ```

   In other words, if `i` is 10, you want `j` to be 13, because that's a chain of length 4 (10,11,12,13).
4. Finally, you need to check costs of all chains in between `i` and `j`. That's why `k` is going from `i` to `j-1`. For the example with chain length `L=4`, you have:

   ```
   L = 4;
   for (i = 1; i <= p.length - 4; i++)
   {
       j = i + 3;
       m[i,j] = MAXINT;
       for (k = i; k <= j - 1; k++)
       { 
           // get the cost of splitting at `k`, 
           // i.e. chains (i, k) and (k + 1, j)
       }
   }
   ```

   In other words, if `L` is 4, and `i` is 10, and `j` is 13, you want to test chains `(10)(11,12,13)`, `(10,11)(12,13)` and `(10,11,12)(13)`. Hence the `k` must go from `i` to `j-1`.

Comment: thanx it was really useful..i cant give +1 as i dnt have enough reputation

Comment: This is a comprehensive answer. I was getting very confused with the limits. Now I understand perfectly. Thank you!